# Как и почему это происходит?

Tags: php, ссылки

Вот код:

```
class reftest
{
    public $a = 1;
    public $c = 1;

    public function reftest()
    {
        $b =& $this->a;
        $b++;
    }

    public function reftest2()
    {
        $d =& $this->c;
        $d++;
    }
}

$reference = new reftest();

$reference->reftest();
$reference->reftest2();

echo $reference->a;
echo $reference->c;
```

Почему выведется **32**?

Comment: А не является ли public function reftest() конструктором?

Comment: Фух, не заметил, что с тем же именем назвал функцию. Зашел на вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/358049/php-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC и начал эксперементировать )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы, названные по имени класса, будут вызваны при создании, как и конструктор. Насколько знаю (а знаю только слухи), это ведется с древних времен, когда конструктором был не `__construct()`, а метод, названный по имени класса (если опять же не ошибаюсь, такая конвенция принята в яве и c++). Другими словами, надо просто переименовать класс или метод `reftest()`.